# Is there any difference between block.timestamp and now?

Tags: solidity, blockchain, remix

I couldn't find any relevant documentation information about the `now` keyword.
However the `now` keyword and `block.timestamp` both return the time of the block function when executed.
Can anyone provide any insight?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any difference between `block.timestamp` and `now`. They're aliases.

But note that in Solidity v0.7.0, the `now` keyword has been deprecated.

Thus, from this version onwards, you should use `block.timestamp` instead of `now` for retrieving the current time of the block.

You can find more information about this change in the [documentation](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/releases/tag/v0.7.0).